# How to call back (display) the images which been extracted before?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, nearest-neighbor, glcm

I've done feature extraction using GLCM and k-nn for classification. What I need to do now is troubleshooting, to analyse why the images been classified wrongly. I want to display the nearest neighbor of the testing data, but not just points like below:

[image: k-nn scatter plot]

I want to display the images that nearest to that image(test), so that is easy to know why is that the images nearest to each other(visually). But here is my problem, I didn't know how to call back the images which been extracted before, since those are presented in array of numbers only.

What should I do?

Comment: This should go to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The [KNeighborsClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) of Scikit-Learn has function [kneighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors) which returns the k-nearest-neigbors' distances and indices. It may help you to find your nearest images for each test image.